# CakePHP validation rule to match field1 and field2

Tags: validation, cakephp, passwords

I am making a password reset form, which contains two fields: password1 and password2. The user enters their new password and then re-types their new password again.

I'm not sure how to make a validation rule that will compare the two values from the fields and see if they're the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using Auth component then you need to hash the second password in the controller, because the password will be automatically hashed.

To compare 2 fields, you need to write a custom validation rule: [http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aranworld/2008/01/14/using-equalto-validation-to-compare-two-form-fields](http://web.archive.org/web/20141022120032/http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/aranworld/2008/01/14/using-equalto-validation-to-compare-two-form-fields) (read the comments also, because the tutorial itself is kind of old)

Answer (score 6):

IMHO it's more trouble than worth to create a separate rule in this case. You could, if you want to code "pure" CakePHP, but it's easier to just compare the fields in the controller and invalidate one of them manually if they don't match:

```
if( $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'password1' ] != $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'password2' ] ) {
    $this->User->invalidate( 'password2', "The passwords don't match." );
}
```

Comment: Yep, but unfortunately there are a ton of other validation rules, and I don't want to make a mess of the controller with them.

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to have written a behavior for this 2 days ago:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/Behavior/PasswordableBehavior.php

some sample code how to use it:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: After upgrading them to 2.x the folder names have been different. Thx for the notification.